# How to break the loop?

Tags: java

everyone who is watching this question. I have a small problem that i am not fixing. I have a program in which a user or a manager can login in and the input check whether the person who logged is a user or a manager. Unfortunately I can't separate them. This is what i would get all the time.

```
Incorrect username or password. Try Again!
```

This is the code:

```
int check = 0;
    while(check == 0)
    {
        screen.displayString("Enter the username:  ");
        String usernameLogin = keypad.getString();
        screen.displayString("Enter the password:  ");
        String passwordLogin = keypad.getString();
        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
            if (users.get(i).getUsername().equals(usernameLogin) && users.get(i).getPassword().equals(passwordLogin)) {
                no = users.get(i).getId();
                check = 1;
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                check = 0;
            }
        }
        if(check == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (manager.getUsername().equals(usernameLogin) && manager.getPassword().equals(passwordLogin)) {
            no = manager.getId();
            check = 1;
            break;
        }
        else {
            check = 0;
        }
        if(check==0)
        {
            screen.displayStringLine("Incorrect username or password. Try Again!");
        }
    }
```

Thank you once again for the help.

Comment: manager is a object of type Manager.  users is a arraylist of User objects. The functions are getter functions of each field of Manager and User.

Comment: any chance you are entering incorrect username or password? Logic looks fine to me

Comment: sairamch04, yeah the username and password are correct because i have them stored in arraylist and i saw them when entering the username and password.

Comment: Does the `getString()` method perhaps insert a newline character in the end? What exactly is `keypad`?

Comment: What does ```keypad.getString()``` return?   For example, do you need to trim a line terminator?  (ha, two of us had the same thought)

Comment: keypad.getString() takes as an input a string. public String getString()
    {
        return input.nextLine();
    }

Comment: Just provide a [mcve]. This problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first off a bit of small advice for code formatting, after each curly brace/code block leave one empty line - it will be easier to read

So let's clean your code a little bit by adhering to these steps:

- do the easier tasks first, meaning there are many users in this app but only one manager so maybe we should check if it's him firstly and not waste compute resources
- remove redundant variables - to break the loop you don't need the `check` variable, only a `break` statement after a correct login
- you can use for each to iterate through a collection

```
while (true) {
    screen.displayString("Enter the username:  ");
    String usernameLogin = keypad.getString();
    screen.displayString("Enter the password:  ");
    String passwordLogin = keypad.getString();

    if (manager.getUsername().equals(usernameLogin) && manager.getPassword().equals(passwordLogin)) {
        no = manager.getId();
        break;
    }

    for (User user : users) {
        if (user.getUsername().equals(usernameLogin) && user.getPassword().equals(passwordLogin)) {
            no = users.get(i).getId();
            break;
        }
    }

    screen.displayStringLine("Incorrect username or password. Try Again!");
}
```

This code should be easier to debug - just place 2 breakpoints on both lines containing `if` statement and check if values are matching.
If you see that everything looks good, check the string encoding - maybe there is a mismatch there (Java uses by default UTF8)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It was helpful because now code could distinguish between manager and users.